# getTableName() for Oracle ResultSetMetaData always returns blank, even though provided a qualifier column name

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I understand there is underlying complexity retrieving column name in case of join select query with * column list. i.e

```
select * from A, B where A.type = B.type
```

Why JDBC driver implementations ignored below example scenario, though we have unique column name.

```
select a.type, a.name, a.value, b.name, b.value, from A, B where A.type = B.type
```

Is there way we can tweak the implementation to handle this scenario?

The issue can be handled if we are building a new app where we can ensure column names are unique across all tables. But dealing with an enterprise application where queries are dynamically built using proper qualifier for columns.

**Note:** reviewed multiple similar posts but no proper direction or solution provided.

Comment: Normally, you should use A.column = B.column , not A.type = B.type. Anyway, show us the code.

Comment: There is nothing you can do. The JDBC driver simply doesn't support this. If you de-compile it, you can see that the implementation of that method is `return "";`

Comment: Agree. The question is about select list how to retrieve table name. Just for illustration.